# Remove duplicate id with different description in sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I have a data like duplicated id but the description is different

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |

How to remove the duplicate? since using DISTINCT will still return all the data

Comment: Remove - like in excluding from SELECT result. or actually DELETE from table?

Comment: Do you want to keep A or B? Why?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You need to describe the entire logic when/how/why to remove which data. If there is another row id 1, name C and a fourth let's say id 1, name A, what should be the result and why?

Comment: I want to keep the first record

Comment: Which is the "first"? Without an order by clause, there is no "first". Also note a table has rows, not records. Please extend your sample data by further rows having other id's and names and add the expected result. Do not use comments to add clarifications to your questions, but edit your question.

Comment: I am using BigQuery and I want to exclude it from SELECT

Comment: Does the table have more columns (not showed here)?

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear from your question in what way really you wish to remove, given that each id has different metadata attached to it.
Do you just want to de-dup the id as single column or u wish to merge its metadata together so only 1 id remains ?

The simplest one is:

select distinct id from ...

But it looks like its not you meant.

So the second option is, you merge the metadata into an array_agg:

```
select id, array_agg(name) as names 
from (select 1 as id, 'A' as name union all select 1 as id, 'B' as name)
group by 1
```

This will remove the id duplication and get all metadata into an array.
[image]

If you are okay with string_agg you can go with that too:

```
select id, string_agg(name) as names 
from (select 1 as id, 'A' as name union all select 1 as id, 'B' as name)
group by 1
```

This will give you comma separated values of names:
[image]

if you want fancier than this , then u can create a struct for your metadata like: (assuming you have more metadata in real project)

```
select id, array_agg(struct(name, info)) as metadata 
from (select 1 as id, 'A' as name, 'X' as info union all select 1 as id, 'B' as name, 'Y' as info)
group by 1
```

this will give you:

[image]

all other options will make you lose some data, like: if you do min(name) or max(name) to consider only one row per id.

If you could clarify your question a bit better, the community can help you more. For now, I see the above options for you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below simple approach

```
select any_value(t).* 
from your_table t
group by t.id
```

if you would have some extra column that identify order of entries - for example ts (timestamp) - you could use below

```
select any_value(t having min ts).* 
from your_table t
group by t.id
```